# Need regex to extract terms separated by space and key/value pairs separated by colon?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to process the keywords from a search field. The idea is to have it act very much like google (ie: support double quoted text to allow for terms with spaces).  Further, I have tags in my dataset that I would like to be able to reference using a color.

A sample input would be:

```
1/2 one two "three & four" five:six seven:"eight nine ten"
```

This should output:

```
1/2
one
two
three & four
five:six
seven:eight nine ten
```

It would also work fine to have 'five' and 'seven' in the same capture group as the other keywords as long as there is another capture group associated with 'six' and 'eight nine ten'.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: research  'lookahead regex'

Comment: @JayBlanchard The closest I've come is with `([^\s"':]+)|("[^"]*"|'[^']*')`

Comment: I think you may be over-complicating it a bit. I'd simply use a regex to extract anything between quotes, strip it out, and then `explode()` with a space as the delimiter. I think looking for a one size fits all regex is always somewhat of a pain. What happens when you want it to do something else? Updating giant, freaknasty regex is painful.

Comment: What about `"three to four"hundred` and `"three or four" hundred`  ?

Comment: `"[^"]*"\S*|(?:[^\s"]+(?:"[^"]*")?)+|"`

Comment: Please also check my [`(?|"([^"]*)"()|([^:\s]+)(?::(?|(\w+)|"([^"]*)"))?)`](https://regex101.com/r/pZ4zY1/1).

Comment: What's to become of us when regex test sites go "belly up and crumble down" ?

Comment: [My idea at eval.in](https://eval.in/518018) which is probably more than needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:**

```
((\"[\s\S]+?\")|[\s\S]+?(:(?2))?)\K(\s+|$)
```

**Substitution:**

```
\r\n
```

**Explanation:**

Get everything and possibly everything in-between quotes (starting with either spaces or a `:`), then resets the regex matching, and then matches any spaces or end of the string.  This means that it only matches the spaces or end of string and then replaces it with a newline.

**Use:**

```
$re = "/((\\\"[\\s\\S]+?\\\")|[\\s\\S]+?(:(?2))?)\\K(\\s+|$)/"; 
$str = "1/2 one two \"three & four\" five:six seven:\"eight nine ten\""; 
$subst = "\r\n"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/jO4oM0/3

*Edit 1: Improved as wasn't properly matching everything properly*
*Edit 2: Shortened*